# Cannot find specific paths when going from local to server

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, aurelia, webpack-4

I am trying to use icons/fonts from my localhost and from a server.
My project structure is as following:
https://files.gitter.im/webpack/webpack/7XUh/image.png
(Cannot insert as image since I do not have 10 reputation yet.)

I have defined all the icons in the assets → images → logos map.
The baseUrl in webpack.config.js is defined as “./”.

I am trying to use the icons as following from my-notifications.scss:
background: white url(/../../assets/images/logos/sample-logo.svg) right 15px center no-repeat;

This is working on my localhost. However, if I open my client on the server, it cannot find the svg files.
The error output in the console is as following:
GET http://server/assets/images/logos/sample-logo.svg 404 (Not Found)

To navigate to my client on the server, I am navigating to: http://server/company/customername/client2

The weird part is that I made a TypeScript model with a name, id and a imagesource. I am using this imagesource (this.imagesrc = './assets/images/logos/sample-image') in another place of my application, and the image source is working there, on localhost and on the server.

Does someone maybe know how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static files are served from your output path but you need to specify your public path as your server:

`http://server/company/customername/client2` that you need to prepend to your generated bundles. You can define this in publicPath:

 `` output: {
    publicPath: `http://server/company/customername/client2`
  }, ``

Then your assets in production will be served from `http://server/company/customername/client2/assets/images/logos/sample-logo.svg`

You can also generate assets at runtime if you're using a CDN. Ref: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#advanced